# Расположение кнопок по центру

Tags: java, android, xml

Есть две кнопки, которые пытаюсь разместить по центру
Именно поэтому решил добавить так сказать ориентир от которого они и будут отталкиваться

```
TextView
        android:id="@+id/centerPoint"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

И теперь в зависимости от кнопки распологаю их следующим образом от центра

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/centerPoint"
```

Аналогично делаю для второй кнопки только справа.
Всё бы хорошо, но текст во второй кнопки длинее и поэтому получается что они всё же расположенны не по центру. Как можно решить сей нюанс?

Comment: Вы хотите разместить две кнопки симметрично относительно центра?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал создать изначально LinearLayout такого типа:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
```

В него закинуть ещё один LinearLayout в котором и будут располагаться Ваши кнопки. У меня это выглядит примерно следующим образом(лишнее можете cмело убирать + кастомные вьюшки замените на свои):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.sai.android.features.common.widget.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/yesterdayView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/todayView"
        android:background="@drawable/button_date_picker_bg_selector"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_6"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_6"
        android:text="@string/common_transactions_select_date_yesterday"
        android:textColor="@color/button_date_picker_text_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
        app:fontType="medium" />

    <com.sai.android.features.common.widget.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/todayView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/button_date_picker_bg_selector"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimen_6"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimen_6"
        android:text="@string/common_transactions_select_date_today"
        android:textColor="@color/button_date_picker_text_selector"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_15"
        app:fontType="medium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием **ConstraintLayout**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="very very very long text" />
    </LinearLayout>
```